# Keyboard symbolums are not working

Tags: keyboard

i have acer aspire 3 laptop. Half(right hand side) of the keyboard symbolism are not working look liker numlk took the control over the right side.

do you guys have any idea how can i fix it ?

AJ

Comment: Try disabling numlock (probably some `Fn` key combination).

Comment: Yes you were right Fn plus NumLK button combination worked. 

Thank you.

Comment: @danzel or user1147753, since it solves the problem, consider writing an answer.